# What does it mean to set the root element's font-size in em units?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I've not been able to find the official definition of `em` units, but I have found this in the spec:

[image]

I've also found a lot of other sources (listed below). This got me thinking, **what does it mean to set the font size of the root element (i.e., `<html>`) to `em` units?** Although a lot of my sources recommend using `em`, I couldn't find any that call out root element usage specifically.

```css
html {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>html { font-size: 1em; }</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>html { font-size: 1.5em; }</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>html { font-size: 0.5em; }</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

In these three above examples, I *see* the difference with my eyes, but what is the correct way to interpret what I'm seeing? In other words, what does `html { font-size: <x>em; }` *mean*?

## Sources

1. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7820/font-size-for-mobile-sites
2. https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-values-4/#em
3. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#font-size
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Comment: "_I've not been able to find the official definition of em units_" https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#font-relative-lengths

Comment: @user I guess I did find it then.  Thanks.

Comment: @isherwood I never noticed that Tidy button before! Thanks for letting me know. BTW, when I said, "I actually think including html and body in the snippets removes potential confusion for the reader" I meant in the context of *this* question, not necessarily in general.

Comment: I hear you. That's a common concern where CSS references those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#font-relative-lengths)

> When used in the value of the font-size property on the element they refer to, the local font-relative lengths resolve against the computed metrics of the parent element—or against the computed metrics corresponding to the **initial values** of the font and line-height properties, **if the element has no parent**.